# Sed command not working as expected

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sed

I am using Ubuntu over WSL. It looks like sed is not working as intended. It doesn't replace the text if the search text in more than one character.

When I execute the following command

`sed 's/l/XYZ/gi'`

it works perfectly fine where as when I switch l to a word like localhost

`sed 's/localhost/XYZ/gi'`

then it stops working. Any pointers?

**Update: I am using sed version 4.4**

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
```

Comment: `sed 's/localhost/XYZ/gi'` works with GNU sed. I am not sure what you have in WSL... Try `sed 's/localhost/XYZ/gI'` or `sed 's/localhost/XYZ/g1'` and see if either one works. Or maybe you are using a very old version of sed then you need to use some regex to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Do a `sed --version` and update your question with the results. Also what does `man sed` say assuming man pages work in WSL

Comment: What is the input to your `sed` command?  Does it happen with any?  What about `sed -n 's/nobody/somebody/p' < /etc/passwd`?

Comment: `sed 's/localhost/XYZ/gi'` works for me as well but piping it to the file doesn't work. @Raffa

Comment: It looks like I am using sed version 4.4 @codlord

Comment: It is still not clear... Please explain more,,, how do you pipe the output? add the actual commands you used and how they did not work for you. Also explain more about the end result you want? what do you expect from your commands? Details can help us understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having just run across something similar in PowerShell's `-replace` just this week, I'm going to theorize that there may be extra characters in your input that you can't see.  Try a `hexdump -C` on the text you are replacing.

For instance, the `wsl.exe` command itself outputs UTF-16 (perhaps even somewhat malformed), which basically puts a 0-byte character after each ASCII character (apologies if my character-encoding terminology isn't quite right):

`wsl.exe -l | hexdump -c`:

```
00000000  57 00 69 00 6e 00 64 00  6f 00 77 00 73 00 20 00  |W.i.n.d.o.w.s. .|
00000010  53 00 75 00 62 00 73 00  79 00 73 00 74 00 65 00  |S.u.b.s.y.s.t.e.|
00000020  6d 00 20 00 66 00 6f 00  72 00 20 00 4c 00 69 00  |m. .f.o.r. .L.i.|
...
```

A `wsl.exe -l | sed 's/W/B/'` will result in:

```
Bindows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu (Default)
...
```

But `wsl -l | sed 's/Windows/GatesOS/'` will fail to replace anything, similar to what you are experiencing:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu (Default)
...
```

If this is the problem you are facing, at least the solution under Linux/WSL is easier than it was under PowerShell.  Just use `iconv` to convert the input from UTF16 to something more manageable, like UTF8:

`wsl.exe -l | iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF8 | sed 's/Windows/GatesOS/'`:

```
GatesOS Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu (Default)
...
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was facing. In my case, the powershell -replace is working fine but sed isn't.

Comment: Luckily my Windows updated to 20H2 yesterday and it started to work again. My current Windows Build (which is working) is 19042.867